# axios post request in if condition has no response data react.js

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, axios, http-post, httpresponse

I want api to send otp but when default_2fa is mobile or email.write this code but respone is null even status code is 200 , i do some test on otpcall outside of if statement and the response work well

```
    const login = (values) => {

     let payload = {
        "input": values.phone_number,
        "password": values.password,
        "user_agent":"postman",
        "client_host":"local"
      }
      axios.post(loginUrl, payload = payload)
          .then(resp => {
            
              if (typeof resp !== 'undefined') {
                   if (resp.data.result.is_2fa_active) {
                    if (resp.data.result.default_2fa === "authenticator_app") {
                        setAuthenticatorApp(true)
                    }
                    if ( resp.data.result.default_2fa === "mobile" || resp.data.result.default_2fa === "email") {
                        let payloadOtp = {
                            "type": resp.data.result.default_2fa,
                            "input": values.phone_number,
                            "password": values.password,
                        }
                         axios.post(otpUrl, payloadOtp).then(response => {
                             setEmailOrSmsAuth(true)
                             return response
                        })
                    }
                  }
              }
          })


  }
```

when i call this api the otp api statuse code is 200 and payload has all values i want but response is null
please help me what is wrong with my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that this problem comes from the server. Below is my solution to fix this.

**CODE**

```
const login = (values) => {

    setIsLoading(true);

    sessionStorage.setItem('mobile', values.phone_number);  //set mobile into local session

    sessionStorage.setItem('password', values.password);  //set password into local session

    const loginUrl = `${BASE_URL(IAM_APP)}/auth/login/`

    let payload = {

        "input": values.phone_number,

        "password": values.password,

        "user_agent": "postman",

        "client_host": "local"

    }

    axios.post(loginUrl, payload)   //request for login if 2factor authentication is true then send to another component

        .then(resp => {

            if (resp !== undefined){
                
                if (resp.data?.result?.access_token) {

                setToken(resp.data.result)

                setTimeout(() => {

                    window.location.href = DASHBOARD

                }, 1000);

            } else if (resp?.data?.result.is_2fa_active === true) {

                if (resp.data.result.default_2fa === "authenticator_app") {

                    history.push(LOGIN2FAAUTHENTICATOR);
                    
                } else if (resp.data.result.default_2fa === "email") {

                    history.push(LOGIN2FAEMAIL);

                } else if (resp.data.result.default_2fa === "mobile") {

                    history.push(LOGIN2FASMS);

                }

            }

        }

        })


}
```

```
then for example in the LOGIN2FASMS route solve issue like this
```

```
const otpSent = () => {   //send otp to mobile

    const otpUrl = `${BASE_URL(IAM_APP)}/auth/2fa/otp/`

    let payloadOtp = {

        "type": "mobile",

        "input": mobile,

        "password": password,

    }

    return axios.post(otpUrl, payloadOtp)

}

useEffect(() => {

    otpSent().then(resp => {

        if (resp?.data?.result === 'otp sent'){
            
        }
        else

            otpSent()

        }

    )

}, [mobile, password]);
```

```
yeah, its done ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you issue is down to the scope of everything.

Because the `.then` only runs once the POST request is complete, the response is only accessible inside of that callback. The intended solution would be to move all your logic into the callback, but that can get messy if you have a lot of subsequent logic.

The alternative (and often preferred) method would be to use a Promise on the request, and then use `await` to wait for the response. This would then return the result to the rest of the logic with the correct scope, allowing you to use it like any other variable. I can't tell what library or method you are using for your POST request, but there is no premade solution for Promises with the library you want, you can wrap your request in a Promise and call that. The syntax will be similar to this:

```js
const postApiPromise = (loginUrl, payload ) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    service.post_api(loginUrl, payload = payload) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply,I use axios(create my own axios),i'll change code for better understanding.I dont figure out how and where i have to use await?